# BKK: International to International connection on different airlines with checked baggage

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, china, bkk

We're flying into Bangkok (BKK) on Bangkok Airways from Siem Reap (REP). In Bangkok were connecting to an international flight from BKK to Beijing (PEK) on Air China. Both flights are considered international.

I am assuming that we'll be heading to the transfer counter to get our boarding passes. If we have to check our bags in Siem Reap what can we do about getting our bags after landing? Since we're on two separate airlines I'm assuming that they won't transfer our bags for us.

Comment: THANKYOU! @dda - when we arrive at Siem Reap should we ask the counter staff to check through our bags? We're not the most experienced international travelers so it would be great to get more info on the process!

Comment: Yup. When the check-in clerk in Siem Reap asks you where you're going, tell Beijing, and provide a printout of both tickets. Makes their life easier. Ask them to check the luggage all the way.

Comment: Did you purchase one airline ticket or two separate ones? If you're booked separate tickets, you may well have to claim and recheck the bags yourself, which will involve going through Thai immigration. if you've booked a single ticket, your bags should be checked through to Beijing when you drop them off in Cambodia, and you can confirm that the baggage tags say PEK on them.

Comment: We have purchased two separate tickets since that is the only way to get to some of the more far flung places in Asia where airlines like Air China do not fly. I think that the advice DDA gave should work!

Comment: Hey DDA, left out one detail and just want to make sure that you don't think it changes the situation. Our final destination is JFK via Air China; would a print out of our full itinerary be sufficient? We don't have boarding passes yet since we have to check in with our passports.

Comment: Yeah print out the whole itinerary. They'll need the flight numbers. You'll get a boarding pass for PEK in BKK. For PEK-JFK you might have to wait to arrive in PEK. But PG should be able to check your luggage all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to check in your bags all the way. Bangkok Airways has [an agreement with plenty of airlines](http://www.bangkokair.com/pages/view/check-in-through), including Air China.